# Grails 3.0.1 Issue connecting to Oracle database

Tags: oracle, grails, jdbc

How should I configure in the application.yml file or anywhere else so my .m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc14\11.1.0\ojdbc14-11.1.0.jar is in the classpath.
Below is my error:

```
:bootRun
ERROR org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Comment: the old config (DataSource.groovy) maps basically 1:1 over into `application.yml`.  please add the relevant parts to the question.

Comment: cfrick   I had that 1:1 mapping. The error tells me that the driver is not in the classpath.  I added this into my application.yml repositories: 
   mavenCentral()
   mavenLocal()
dependencies:
   classpath: com.oracle:ojdbc14:11.1.0    
The error said that repositories is not a mapping value.  Thanks, mnva

Comment: please edit the question and all all relevant informations (datasource part of app.yml, these deps, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (Grails 3.0.2 + Oracle 12c). The guys in my post helped me fix it: [How-to: Grails 3.0.2 + Oracle Database 12c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126177/how-to-grails-3-0-2-oracle-database-12c) . Credits should of course go to them.

Answer (score 0):

Just Paste your ***ojdbc14-11.1.0.jar*** to these 2 directory

- **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext**
- **C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\lib\ext**