# Adding ojdbc7_g to Grails3.3.8

Tags: oracle, grails, ojdbc

I am getting Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver running my Grails3.3.8 Application.

I already followed the steps in [How-to: Grails 3.0.2 + Oracle Database 12c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126177/how-to-grails-3-0-2-oracle-database-12c) but it still doesn't seem to work.

Any details steps on how to do this is appreciated.

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
compile "org.grails:grails-core"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
compile "org.grails.plugins:events"
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.5.Final"
compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
//compile files(lib/ojdbc7_g.jar)
//compile "com.oracle:ojdbc7:12.1.0.1.0"
console "org.grails:grails-console"
profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
runtime "com.h2database:h2"
runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.14.8"
//runtime "com.oracle.ojdbc7:12.1.0.1.0"
testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb:1.1.2"
testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:2.47.1"
testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
}
```

Comment: Please share the relevant parts from your `build.gradle`.

Comment: updated my post with dependencies in build.gradle. i've tried those commented parts and still doesn't work. as for the version 12.1.0.1.0, i have verified that is the version of my ojdbc7_g.jar